# Intuition behind a convergent subsequence of $\sin(n)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, intuition

$\let\eps\varepsilon$

I was looking through a Real Analysis exam paper one day and was stuck on a question; fortunately there is a solution provided which I will sketch below, but I have no intuition on how I would have come up with this proof.

Question: Find an *explicit* convergent subsequence of $\sin(n)$ and prove it converges.

My first guess was to try $ \sin\lfloor 2\pi n\rfloor  $ (or ceiling instead of floor) and hope $\lfloor 2\pi n \rfloor$ will approximate some multiple of $2\pi$  reasonably well for large $n$. However, on reflection this probably won't work because a subsequence of this is $\sin\lfloor 2\pi \cdot 10^n \rfloor $, and (ignoring sign) $2\pi \cdot 10^n -\lfloor 2\pi \cdot 10^n \rfloor$ is the fractional part of $2\pi\cdot 10^n$ which I have no idea how to control, much less inside of a $\sin$.

After this I was stuck for a good number of hours and eventually gave up. The solution given, is amazingly similar to my attempt: it uses the subsequence 
    $$a_n := \sin \sqrt{\left\lceil (2\pi n)^2 \right\rceil} \equiv \sin b_n$$
It is perhaps at this point I should note that the question did say to instead find a subsequence of $\sin\sqrt{n}$ instead; but I thought I was simplifying the question as $\sin(n) = \sin\sqrt{n^2}$ is a subsequence of $\sin \sqrt{n}$.

Anyway, the answer drops out after a little work. Noting that we can write 
    $$b_n = 2\pi n + \eps_n, \quad \eps_n\in [0,1) $$
and making the easy approximation (which was given as a hint) $|\sin x | \leq |x|$, one obtains
    $$|\sin b_n| = 
\left|\sin \left[\sqrt{\left\lceil (2\pi n)^2 \right\rceil} - 2\pi n\right]\right| 
\leq
2\pi \left|n\sqrt{1+\frac{\eps_n}{4\pi^2n^2}} - n\right| 
$$

And by Bernoulli's inequality, $(1+\eps)^n \geq 1+n\eps$, applied with $n=2$,
$$ \sqrt{1+\frac{\eps_n}{4\pi^2}} \leq 1 + \frac{\eps_n}{8\pi^2n^2} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 1$$

Thus $|\sin b_n|$ is bounded by a null sequence; by the Sandwich Rule it is itself null, which concludes the proof.

Notably, trying the above argument for $\sin\lceil 2\pi n \rceil$ gives you the very useless
 $$|\sin(2\pi n + \eps_n) | = | \sin(2\pi n + \eps_n - 2\pi n) | \leq \eps_n$$

How did the author of the exam come up with this solution? Is there anything intuitive in retrospect you can share? (I would appreciate more answers that don't say 'the exam question was phrased in a way to hint to the expected answer', because I find this a little unsatisfactory)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an attempt to provide intuition as to why we can work with $\sin(\sqrt x)$ in a way that we can't with $\sin(x)$:

- The [equidistribution theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistribution_theorem) tells us that $2 \pi n - \lfloor 2 \pi n \rfloor$ will stay "evenly" spread out between $0$ and $1$. On average, it will "miss the mark" of $0$ by $1/2$.  Not particularly useful in producing an upper bound for this difference, but a good explanation of how "uncontrollable" this sequence is
- The function $f(x) = \sin(\sqrt{x})$ becomes "more spread-out" as $x \to \infty$ (that is, $f'(x) \to 0$).  As a result, if we can get a sequence $x_n$ such that $|x_n - (2 \pi n)^2| \leq 1$, we will find that 
  $$
  \lim_{n \to \infty} \left|f([2 \pi n]^2) - f(x_n)\right|
  = \lim_{n \to \infty} f'(c_n)\left|(2 \pi n)^2 - x_n\right|
   \to 0
  $$
  Where the appropriate $c_n$ is chosen between $2 \pi n$ and $x_n$.  Such a $c_n$ is guaranteed to exist by the mean value theorem.
- The function $\sin(x)$ does not exhibit this behavior

Comment: I like this, thank you. Though there is no way the first year undergrad student this exam was meant for would be able to understand rigourously differentiation and the mean value theorem, much less ergodic theory!

Comment: I suppose that this sort of intuition is earned :P.  I am curious as to how a first year undergraduate student ended up in an analysis course.  That being said, I think that anyone in the middle of an analysis course should have enough intuition with calculus to understand the broad strokes of those last two statements, even if they are not able to prove them rigorously.

Comment: I should also point out that in order to answer the question, a student need only see that this is possible with $\sin(\sqrt{x})$ and not that it is impossible with $\sin(x)$.  The equidistribution statement would be useful for a construction for the latter, if perhaps not an explicit one.

Comment: Well I'm not too sure what 'analysis course' means to you. This is in the UK if it helps? and this module named 'Analysis 1' treating sequences and series rigourously(continuous functions appear only in Analysis 2) is effectively this university's 'Introduction to Proofs' (in my opinion).

Comment: Perhaps things are done differently in the US.  Typically the progression begins with Calculus (the "rigor-free" version, with perhaps a mention of the $\epsilon, \delta$ definition of limits/continuity).  This may include multivariate calculus.
Then comes linear algebra (and possibly differential equations).  Then comes analysis (or algebra), which is generally a student's first encounter with true rigor.  I suppose that neither multivariate calculus nor linear algebra is really required for analysis, but the jump in rigor is fairly daunting even with the progression.

Comment: It is different then; the progression might have been nice when I was in first year. Oh well, I will never know :)